# React Native - Installing npm libraries results in other packages to be broken OR running application further not running on Android/iOS

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

**I am new to React Native. When I try to add a new library package into my project, the package will be installed properly. But, then further app will not be in running position OR the existing packages installed will be in broken condition. Why does this happens ?**

**I tried to install below package**

```
npm i react-native-select-dropdown
```

**Now when I hit the below command**

```
react-native run-android
```

**This results in app not running and the node window which is opened, will get closed and the running is stucked at 91% OR 99%**
[image]